# Can't filter in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I am creating an API in ruby on rails and I have 3 tables `Invoice`, `Package` and `Additional_charge`.

`Invoice` has many `Packages` and `Packages` has many `Additional_charges`

I have this query:

```rb
invoices = Invoice.includes(packages: :additional_charges)
                      .where(user_id: @current_user.id)
                      .order(created_at: :desc)

@invoices = invoices.paginate(page:, per_page:)
```

And I am using `jbuilder` to return the data.
This is my `jbuilder` file.

```rb
json.invoices @invoices do |invoice|
  json.(invoice, :id, :number, :total, :status, :created_at)
  json.packages invoice.packages do |package|
    json.(package, :tracking, :calculated_weight, :price)
    json.type package.shipping_method
    json.additional_charges package.additional_charges do |additional_charge|
      json.(additional_charge, :name, :amount)
    end
  end
end
```

But the problems is when I tried to filter for a `Packages` column named `Tracking`.

I tried modifying the code like this:

```rb
invoices = Invoice.includes(packages: :additional_charges)
                      .where(user_id: @current_user.id)

invoices = invoices.where('packages.tracking ILIKE ?', "%#{tracking}%") if tracking.present?

@invoices = invoices.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:, per_page:)
```

And I got this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "packages"
> LINE 1: ...M "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."user_id" = $1 AND (packages.t...

Is there a way so I can filter by `trackin` column from `Packages` table?

I tried using joins too but the `jbuilder` returns me repeated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is how `includes` works.

When using `includes` Rails tries to infer whether or not to use `eager_load` or `preload`. This inference is based on the existence of query conditions provided to `where`, the problem is Rails no longer (hasn't for a very long time) tries to parse string conditions to determine if an associated table is referenced.

For example:

- This will use `preload` - `invoices = Invoice.includes(packages: :additional_charges)` because neither `packages` nor `additional_charges` are referenced
- This will also use `preload` - `invoices = Invoice.includes(packages: :additional_charges).where('packages.tracking ILIKE ?', "%#{tracking}%")` because Rails cannot determine that `packages` is referenced in the String condition

  - `preload` will execute 2 queries the first to collect the objects from the primary table (invoices) and another query to collect all of the associated packages e.g. (in simplified form removing the additional_charges portion for demonstration purposes)

```
SELECT invoices.* FROM invoices 
SELECT packages.* FROM packages WHERE packages.invoice_id IN (1,2,3)
```

- This will use `eager_load` - `invoices = Invoice.includes(packages: :additional_charges).where(packages: {tracking: '123'})` because rails can infer the need to join the `packages` table based on the condition.

  - `eager_load` will left join the "included" tables and collect all of the data at the same time in 1 query e.g.

```
SELECT invoices.id AS t0_r0, invoices.number AS t0_r1,...packages.id AS t1_r0, packages.tracking AS t1_r1,... FROM invoices LEFT OUTER JOIN packages ON packages.invoice_id = invoices.id
```

In your case the issue is that your implementation uses `preload` and therefor the packages table is not included in the main query; however, you are referencing it in your String condition in where, which causes the error you are seeing.

The simplest resolution would be to use [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#references](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references)

`references` removes the inference by Rails and instead explicitly tells Rails that this table is referenced, so your code would change to

```
invoices = invoices.references(packages: :additional_charges).where('packages.tracking ILIKE ?', "%#{tracking}%") if tracking.present?
```

Comment: Thank you! The first option gave me the correct result but the second options I got an error, but still very very helpful your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `includes` doesn't always generate a join, sometimes it will perform an extra query for the included data. I believe it would normally be able to detect the use of a referenced table in a where, but because of your string query for the ILIKE it isn't picking that up.

I think you can just add a `joins(:packages)` to your query (with the `includes`) and that should solve it.

Or you could go for just the explicit `joins` but add a `distinct` to that to get rid of the duplicates, that's a quite common pattern.